# CloudHaskell running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, haskell, amazon-ec2, cloud-haskell

I have created 3 EC2 Ubuntu instances on AWS and trying to run this code:

```
module Main where

remotableDecl [ [d|
  distribute :: ([NodeId], Int) -> Process ()
  distribute (slaves, x) = do
    let x' = myMath x
        nextNode = slaves !! (x' `mod` (length slaves))
    say $ show x ++ " - 1 = " ++ show x'
    unless (x' == 0) $
      void $ spawn nextNode $ $(mkClosure 'distribute) (slaves, myMath x)
  |]]

remoteTable = __remoteTableDecl initRemoteTable

master :: Backend -> [NodeId] -> Process ()
master backend slaves = do
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Slaves: " ++ show slaves
  distribute (slaves, 15)
  terminateAllSlaves backend

main :: IO ()
main = do
  prog <- getProgName
  args <- getArgs

  case args of
    ["master", host, port] -> do
      backend <- initializeBackend host port remoteTable
      startMaster backend (master backend)
    ["slave", host, port] -> do
      backend <- initializeBackend host port remoteTable
      startSlave backend
```

by these commands as stated here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-simplelocalnet-0.2.3.2/docs/Control-Distributed-Process-Backend-SimpleLocalnet.html

$ stack exec -- test slave 172.31.3.226 8080 &

$ stack exec -- test slave 172.31.3.227 8080 &

$ stack exec -- test master 172.31.3.228 8080

IPs are private IPs of AWS instances. But when I run as master, there is no slaves connected. This is the output:

Slaves: []

Tue Jul 26 17:45:04 UTC 2016 pid://172.31.3.228:8000:0:10: 15 - 1 = 14

test: divide by zero

There should be slaves connected in the output, but there is not.

Comment: What is your question, and what output are you currently getting?

Comment: Edited the output, there should be slaves connected but there isn't. What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you look at the suggestion in the manual? `If you try the above example and the master process cannot find any slaves, then it might be that your firewall settings do not allow for UDP multicast (in particular, the default iptables on some Linux distributions might not allow it).`

Comment: Yes, I enabled UDP multicast.